# PySpark - top-n words from multiple files files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a python dictionary:

```
diction = {'1.csv': 'this is is a test test test ', '2.txt': 'that that was a test test test'}
```

I have created an RDD  like this:

```
docNameToText = sc.parallelize(diction)
```

I need to calculate find the top-2 strings appearing in each document. So, the result should look something like this:

```
1.txt, test, is
2.txt, test, that
```

I am new to pyspark, I know the algorithm, but not sure how to do it is pyspark. I need to:

```
- convert the file-to-string => file-to-wordFreq
- arrange wordFreq in non-increasing order - if two words have the same freq, arrange them in alphabetical order
- display the top 2
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter 

(sc
    .parallelize(diction.items())
    # Split by whitepace
    .mapValues(lambda s: s.split())
    # Count
    .mapValues(Counter)
    # Take most commont
    .mapValues(lambda c: [x for (x, _) in c.most_common(2)]))
```

Comment: thanks! Minor clarification: what if I also wanted to put results in alphabetical order if two words have the same count? For example, for '1.csv', result should be ['test', 'that'] and not ['that', 'test']. Thanks.